# k-Travelling Salesman optimization

Tags: algorithm

Given a weighted graph which current I have more than 100 nodes. The question is then how to find shortest tour through an array of nodes (10 nodes for instances) which belongs to the built graph. The question seems similar to traveling salesman problem but it's not.

My current solution is quite straightforward
Step 1: Build a new graph from array of 10 nodes which I have to construct tour from
Step 2: Use Dijkstra to find distance between nodes and connect all the vertices in the graph
Step 3: Now it simply turns into traveling salesman problem

Easy. However, step 2 complexity is O(n^2) since I have to find shortest path (which Dijkstra having polynomial complexity) for all combination of nodes of new graph.

How can I make my algorithm faster? Best case being I can eliminate the bottleneck of having to find shortest distance for every pair combinations of nodes in my new graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dijkstra](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/45514/Dijkstras-algorithm) has complexity of O(E log(N)), if you have complete graph (which you have, if you are doing TSP), than you can write it as O(N² log(N)), for all pairs of nodes it is O(N⁴ log(N)). Hence it should be more efficient to use [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/45708/Floyd-Warshall-algorithm), which finds shortest path among all pairs of nodes in O(N³).