# Algorithm to find matchup for a group with n players and m participant matches

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, schedule

I have the following problem:

> A group of n players wants to play a set of matches. Each match has m 
>   participants. I want to find a schedule with a minimum number of games
>   where every player meets every other player at least once and maximum
>   variety of opponents.

After some research I found that the "social golfer problem" seems to be a similar problem but I could not find a solution which I could adapt nor can I come up with an own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode (assuming there are flags inside the players):

```
function taking array of players (x) and players per game (y) {
    array of players in this game (z)
    for each player (t) in x {
        if z.length == y {break out of loop}
        check the flag of each player in (t), if the flag is not set {
            check if z.length is less than y {
                set flag and add it to array z
            }
        }
    }
    if z.length is less than 2, change the players in z's flags back to false
    return (if z.length == 3, return z, or else return false);
}
```

Start with player A; (assume players A to F, 3 players per game)

By going through from top to bottom, we can eliminate possibilities. Start with each person playing all other players (that they have not already played, so for example, B skips C because B played with C in ABC) (in groups of 3). We can write a function to do this (see psuedocode at top)

```
A B C (save this game to a list of games, or increment a counter or something)
A D E
A F -missing (returned false so we did not save this)
B D E 
B F -missing
C D E
C F -missing 
D E F
```

Now, almost all players have played each other, if you only count the groups of 3. This is 5 games so far. Remove the games we've already counted, resulting in

```
A F -missing
B F -missing
C F -missing
```

What is in common here? They all have F. That means that F must play everyone in this list, so all we need to do is put F in the front.

We can now do F A B, and then C F + any random player. This is the minimum 7 games.

Basically, you can run the pseudocode over and over until it returns false 2 times in a row. When it has returned false 2 times in a row, you know that all flags have been set.

Comment: my problem is that assuming i have 4 players in each match i need an approach to create the match-up. If i just combine with for loops and ensure everyone sees everyone once i will probably have much more games than i would need to.

Comment: Lets pretend i have 6 players plaing a 3-player game. There are 20 combinations i can form within the group but i can create a set of 7 matches after whcih everyone has seen everyone. Example:
abc,def,cde,abf,dae,bde,cfX

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete solution, but... Consider a graph with `n` nodes. A match with `m` players can be represented by laying `m-1` edges into the graph per round. The requirement that each player meet each other player at least once means that you will after some number of rounds have a [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph).

For round (match) 1, lay an arbitrary set of `m-1` edges. For each next round, lay `m-1` edges that are not currently connecting two nodes. Repeat until the graph is complete.

**Edit:** Edges would need to be laid connected to ensure only `m` players are in a match for `m-1` edges, which would make this a little more difficult. If you lay each round in a walk of the complete graph, the problem is then the same as finding the shortest walk of the complete graph. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15703354/118098) to a different question may be relevant, and suggests the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/45708/Floyd-Warshall-algorithm).